# C++ class implementation namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

I have files `MyClass.hpp` and `MyClass.cpp`

MyClass.hpp

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void method1();
    void method2();
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
void MyClass::method1() {
}

void MyClass::method2() {
}
```

I find it a little silly that I have to write out the `MyClass::` every time I have to write a method implementation. Is there some sort of syntactic sugar that lets me just group all my implementation together?

Perhaps something like

```
namespace MyClass {
    void method1() {
    }

    void method2() {
    }
}
```

I don't mind using C++11 features, but I would like to stick with portable solutions.

EDIT:

I realize that the code above as written wouldn't work. I was just using it as an illustration of how I imagine some syntactic sugar would work to make things more convenient.

Comment: `MyClass` is not a namespace. You'll have to stick to the silly way.

Comment: @juanchopanza I realize the code wouldn't run as written. I was just hoping there might something similar that I could use to group them. Perhaps if I could reopen classes like in some other languages?

Comment: In-line definition of members in `class`'s definition, but seriously not recommended.

Comment: It is the syntax you have to follow if you define any member function outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The *only* way is to define your member functions directly inside the class definition, which makes them `inline` and may or may not be what you want.

Personally, I reckon having function definitions in *source* files is well worth having to type out a class name once in each.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other-way. You have to  repeat MyClass::

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to identify a method using namespace. In a namespace there can be several classes, non-member methods .... Since a class method can be defined in any source file (other than the header declaring the class itself), you have to specify which class a method belongs to while defining it.

Comment: I'm not looking to treat classes like a namespace per se. I am looking for syntactic sugar to make it easier to write groups of implementations. As it stands there's a lot of repetition. The sample code is just an example of how I imagine this syntactic sugar might be implemented. As such your answer seems irrelevant.